# MySQL: wait/synch/sxlock/innodb/fil_space_latch understanding

Tags: mysql, locking, amazon-rds, innodb

Our system was down recently as the database had exceeded the max_connection. We are using AWS RDS - Aurora MySQL.

Checking Performance Insights, we noticed that a query is the main factor. The query itself is totally fine, however, `wait/synch/sxlock/innodb/fil_space_latch` take 99% time consuming.

So I would like to understand what the metric is, especially what `fil_space_latch` does

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised this question to AWS support and got answer as below:

> The "fil_space_latch" is a wait event caused by locks acquired on
> operation related to tablespace.  It can be indication of increased
> workloads.  If for example, a temporary table is created when a JOIN
> or SELECT query is executed with a large numbers of tables and records
> queried, I/O operation to the temporary table will occur and the
> increased of this wait event can be see.
>
> Refer to:
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/fil0fil_8h.html#aa4426c0c081c18110a1047501c05b1b3
>
> This can be observed from the DB metric 'Created_tmp_tables' and
> 'Innodb_rows_inserted' relevant to the query waits at the time in the
> Performance Insights of the target instance.